# Scroll a grid of buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

This code does not make the scroll bar work. It keeps where it is.

```
from tkinter import *       
from tkinter.ttk import *
 
root = Tk()      
root.geometry('400x400')    

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

scroll = Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
scroll.pack(side="right", fill = "y")

canvas = Canvas(frame)
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

#canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set) if I uncomment this, it still doesn't work
scroll.config(command=canvas.yview)

for fila in range(50):
    for col in range(3):
        btn = Button(canvas, text = f"{fila}-{col}")
        btn.grid(row=fila, column=col)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You just needed to put your frame into a canvas window object and use `grid` manager.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has been rearranged a little.

I've included a canvas window object to hold the frame that holds the buttons.

Canvas now has a `scrollregion` which is necessary when using `Scrollbars`

I find `grid` manager gives more precise control over widget positioning than `pack`

Oh, and I've used a `LabelFrame` instead of a standard `Frame`.

```py
import tkinter as tk
 
root = tk.Tk()      
# essential to enable full window resizing
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

# scrollregion is also essential when using scrollbars
canvas = tk.Canvas(
    root, scrollregion = "0 0 2000 1000", width = 400, height = 400)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient = tk.VERTICAL, command = canvas.yview)
scroll.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.NS)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand = scroll.set)

# I've used a labelframe instead of frame so button are neatly collected and named
frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, labelanchor = tk.N, text = "Buttonpad")

# Note I've placed buttons in frame
for fila in range(20):
    for col in range(5):
        btn = tk.Button(frame, text = f"{fila}-{col}")
        btn.grid(row = fila, column = col, sticky = tk.NSEW)

# Frame is now inserted into canvas via create_window method
item = canvas.create_window(( 2, 2 ), anchor = tk.NW,  window = frame )

root.mainloop()
```